# wingIDE not working on kali linux no error message

Tags: python, kali-linux, wing-ide

there is no error message it just does not open no matter how long i wait i have the icon ready i depackaged everything but had to force install it and it does not work.

[message after install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pnua1.png)

ANY HELP WILL BE APPRECIATED THANKS

Comment: am getting error message now "Failed to execute command"wing7.2%F".Failed to execut child process"wing7.2"(No such file or directory)"

Comment: "*package architecture (amd64) does not match system (i386)*" "*dependency problems*" "*Removing wingpro7:amd64 (7.2.2-0)*"

Comment: Here is a link to the Wing Pro troubleshooting guide, https://wingware.com/doc/install/trouble. Can you run through some of the troubleshooting steps and see if you can narrow down the cause?

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0):

From the message "package architecture (amd64) does not match system (i386)" it looks like your system is 32-bit Linux and Wing 7 only runs on 64-bit Linux.  Using --force-all for installation won't solve that.  You can use Wing Pro's remote development support to develop on 32-bit Linux, by running Wing on a system that is supported and pointing it at the 32-bit system as the remote host (see https://wingware.com/hints/remote-dev-2 for details) but you can't run the IDE itself on 32-bit Linux.